# User path with username

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, path, friendly-id

To show User's profile I used their id. In controller:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
```

In routes:

```
get ':id' => 'users#show'
```

But now I try new way with username:

```
get ':username' => 'users#show' #route

@user = User.find_by(username: params[:username]) #controller
```

And when I go to user's profile with `/username` 
I see error: `undefined method posts`. In controller I get user's posts. But now it doesn't works. Please tell me why?
And I have one more question. When I go to `/users` or `/posts` or something else, my app thinks, that I go to uset's page. How to fix it? And what to do, if user sign up with, for example, username: "users"?

Comment: show us the`PostsController` and your route file

Comment: And possibly rake routes and where the `posts` method is called that throws the error.

Comment: Where do you use the `posts` method that it's failing on?

Comment: In sum, I decide to use gem friendly-id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Artyom you can use the [friendly-id gem](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) if you want to make this process easier on you. Ryan Bates has a [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid?view=asciicast) on it as well.

That way you can use strings as ids (i.e. your `username`) in the url:

```
http://localhost:3000/articles/hello-world
```

Let me know if you have any questions,

-Dave

Comment: I add this gem. Then I add this code in User model:  `extend FriendlyId
 friendly_id :username`. But it still diesn't works. P.S. I use devise gem.

Comment: Did you follow the **Rails Quickstart** instructions for installing FriendlyId on their [git page](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id)? There are a few steps you need to take before it will work. What errors are you getting? Here is another valuable video tutorial [GoRails #9](https://gorails.com/episodes/pretty-urls-with-friendly-id) as well.

Comment: Now it works, thank you. The problem was in case-sensitivity. I enter the username in the address bar incorrectly. So, how to remove case-sensitivity?

Comment: For case sensitivity, just use downcase on the id param before checking it. `User.friendly.find(params[:id].downcase)` should work.